# The meaning of "Referenced" in process smaps

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel

I am trying to understand the meaning of "Referenced" in the smaps file of a process.
According to the kernel documentation:

> "Referenced" indicates the amount of memory currently marked as referenced or
>   accessed."

I understand the meaning of "accessed", but what does it mean "referenced"?
If it is all accessed memory, then I expect it to be "RSS" + "Swap", but in the following example, it is not like that.

Example:

```
7f13e7577000-7f13e75c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
Size:                296 kB
Rss:                 156 kB
Pss:                 156 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         4 kB
Private_Dirty:       152 kB
Referenced:          128 kB
Anonymous:           156 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                 56 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [Linux kernel source code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/page-flags.h?v=4.1#L39) that defines the `referenced` flag bit for memory pages,

> `PG_referenced`, `PG_reclaim` are used to reclaim pages for anonymous, file-backed pagecache.

The `referenced` flag bit is used in [**`page_check_references()`**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=4.1;i=page_references) where is is further documented as,

```
/*
* All mapped pages start out with page table
* references from the instantiating fault, so we need
* to look twice if a mapped file page is used more
* than once.
*
* Mark it and spare it for another trip around the
* inactive list. Another page table reference will
* lead to its activation.
*
* Note: the mark is set for activated pages as well
* so that recently deactivated but used pages are
* quickly recovered.
*/
```

Also [**`mark_page_accessed()`**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/swap.c?v=4.1#L595) is the function called from various places within the Linux kernel documents the updates to the `referenced` flag bit of a page through the initial part of its lifecycle:
(i.e. starting from when a page is newly allocated)

```
* Mark a page as having seen activity.
*
* inactive,unreferenced  ->  inactive,referenced
* inactive,referenced    ->  active,unreferenced
* active,unreferenced    ->  active,referenced
*
* When a newly allocated page is not yet visible, so safe for non-atomic ops,
* __SetPageReferenced(page) may be substituted for mark_page_accessed(page).
*/
```

> i.e. `referenced` = active page-cache that is NOT going to be reclaimed anytime soon.